# Using Instance Variables Across Modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, mixins

Here's an example of a script that I want to be able to support:

```
class Testing
  include Dialect

  url_is 'http://localhost:9292'
end

@page = Testing.new
@page.view
```

The things to note here are:

1. I'm including a Dialect module. (Code shown below.)
2. I'm calling a url_is() method directly on the class.
3. I'm calling a view() method on an instance of the class.

The url_is() method is going to set a @url variable. The view() method ideally would be able to read that variable. That is what I don't seem to be able to do. Here is the code that supports the above script:

```
module Dialect
  module Generator
    module Assertion
      def url_is(url)
        @url = url
      end
    end
  end
end

module Dialect
  def self.included(caller)
    caller.extend Dialect::Generator::Assertion
  end

  def view
    puts "#{@url}"
  end
end
```

Here you can see that when Dialect is included, I have an included method that extends my Assertion module. That allows url_is() to work and url_is() does set the instance variable. You can also see I define view() which I want to be able to access that @url variable.

It's the latter part that's not happening. I get why in that I'm trying to read a variable from the Dialect::Generator::Assertion module in the Dialect module but I'm not sure what the best approach is to allow this.

I investigated [module and class variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534498/module-and-class-variable-scope-in-ruby) and [Ruby mixins and instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875896/ruby-mixins-and-instance-variables) but I haven't found anything that I can determine deals with the situation I'm describing.

Comment: Instance variable inside a module? :-/

Comment: @uDaY I take you feel that an instance variable here is not even the appropriate approach? I'm fine with a different approach, as long as the script I provided can run the same way: meaning using some elements, like url_is(), directly on the class and others, like view(), on instances of the class.

Comment: Module cannot be instantiated like a class. So I was wondering why you need an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by the *class instance variable* `@view`.

When you access an instance variable, the "instance" being referred to is `self`. In an instance method, `self` is the instance of the class (as you would expect). In a class, `self` is the class itself (an instance of `Class`)! This should illustrate the distinction:

```
class Foo
  @x = 0

  def initialize
    @x = 1
  end

  def self.x
    @x
  end

  def x
    @x
  end
end

Foo.x # 0
Foo.new.x # 1
Foo.x # still 0, they are entirely separate variables
```

When you extend `Dialect::Generator::Assertion`, `url_is` is added as a class method to `Test`, so `@url` is being set as an instance variable for `Test` itself. But when you include `Dialect`, `view` is added as an instance method to `Test` so the `@url` it is accessing is for an *instance* of `Test`.

In the `view` method, you can simply specify that you need the class version of the variable

```
def view
  self.class.class_eval { "#{@url}" }
end
```

Comment: `def view; @@url; end` is better ;)

Comment: Ah, got it. So another way I could do this is put in a `def url; @url; end` method in Dialect::Generator::Assertion and then, in my view() method I could just call that method, as in `self.class.url`. This all makes a lot more sense now and you were correct: I was confusing the elements I was working with.

Comment: @mdesantis class instance variables aren't the same thing as class variables. He would need to rewrite most of his code in order to use `@@url`.

Comment: @Max you are right, I get always confused between them >.<